# Solving an application using Observer and Observable

Tags: java, observable

I have a application and i need to user Observer to resolve. Since the code implementation is long i would like to sum the problem.

I start the application.

I have a LogInWindow where i can choose Secretary or Student.

The secretary can add students, courses and results for a student at a given course.
The student can only see its results.

I need to use Observer so that if a Secretary is Logged in an instance of that application and a Student is logged in another instance of that application, when the Secretary adds a result for that student at a course, that student sees instantly on its list that new course and its result.

The data is read from txt files.

My solution.
SecretaryWindow is an Observer
StudentWindow is an Observer
ResultRepositoryFile is the Observable object

When i click AddButton the controller Adds a Result(studentName, courseName, result) to the ResultRepositoryFile. The SecretaryWindow observer sees that, prints a message and saves the txt file containing the ResultRepositoryFile.

Now in StudentWindow i click a RefreshButton and the ResultRepositoryFile is reloaded in the list from this window, showing the newly added Result.class

Is this the right way to do it, because i have doubts.

How to sync the two instances of the same application using Observer ?

Thanks for reading and hope you can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to have more than one person using your application at the same time, you should use a database, rather than text files.  Text files can get corrupted if more than one person writes to them at the same time.

I suggest a relational database like MySQL.

Since your student window has a refresh button, your student window will always pull the most recent data from the database.

When the secretary adds a result to the database, the database will lock, and not allow anyone to access that one and only result until after the add is committed to the database.  The database allows access to other results at the same time the secretary is adding a result.

You do not need an Observed and Observable, unless you want to signal a student that a secretary has added a result to the database.

Edited to add:

The secretary window is the Observed, and the Observable is the result that the secretary has added to the text file.

The student window updates the window based on the Observable.  The secretary window has to be able to access the student window instance based on the student id of the result.

Comment: +1. Excellent suggestion of using MySQL rather than text-files. However important you think this is, you're wrong. It's actually more important than that ;) . Also, I think the use of the Observable pattern is mandatory here (I suspect it's in the requirements).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately the data is read from txt files and the use of Observable is mandatory (assignment requirements).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately the data is read from txt files and the use of Observable is mandatory (assignment requirements). I just cant figure out how to implement the "update" for StudentWindow so that when the Secretary adds a new result for that Student, the result appears automatically on that StudentWindow without pressing RefreshButton. Or is some kind of Refresh input necessary ? The application has 2 mains, on one you have SecretaryWindow, on other StudentWindow, isnt the txt data files the only thing they have in common ? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are bit keen on using observer design pattern.Say you haven't read design pattern, how will you implement it.Here is the way i would approach this problem. Student will have a flag result added and an association for result objectWhen seceratary add the results
for a subject, he will find all the logged in studdents who are have opted for subject for which secretary going to add result and simply
mark the result flag as true(obviously text file/db also needs to be updated) .This is the case when you don't want to hit the DB/file just to fetch whether result got added or not , probably
because of some performance factor.Now when student refreshes the page he can simply bring it from result object instead of fetching from db.
Personally i would prefer firing ajax call(basically polling) instead of refresh